# OSX Caffe Compilation Fails With Expected Expression Error

Tags: python, macos, machine-learning, caffe

I have been trying to install Caffe on my mac running OSX 10.13.6

I have followed several guides, including the installation guide on the caffe site. I have erased everything and restarted several times. I get the same problem no matter what. When I go to compile everything I am getting this

`Scanning dependencies of target caffeproto
[  1%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffeproto.dir/__/__/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc.o
In file included from /Users/Name/Documents/Programming/PythonEnv/caffe/build/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc:4:
In file included from /Users/Name/Documents/Programming/PythonEnv/caffe/build/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:9:
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h:209:17: error: expected
      expression
  OnShutdownRun([](const void* p) { delete static_cast<const T*>(p); }, p);
                ^
In file included from /Users/Name/Documents/Programming/PythonEnv/caffe/build/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc:4:
In file included from /Users/Name/Documents/Programming/PythonEnv/caffe/build/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:25:
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_table_driven.h:34:
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map.h:49:
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map_type_handler.h:35:
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:43:
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/message_lite.h:117:3: error: unknown type
      name 'constexpr'
  constexpr const T& get() const { return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(union_); }`

I have also tried using CMake and run into the same problem. I'm not sure where to go from here. I am not incredibly knowledgable about building processes so I apologize if this is vague and will be happy to provide whatever other information might help fix this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If compiling with `make`, change `Makefile` as follows:

`- CXXFLAGS += -pthread -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(WARNINGS)`

`+ CXXFLAGS += -pthread -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(WARNINGS) -std=c++11`

Answer (score 2):

This is the same problem as reported here: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/57093#comment:1

The compiler needs to be using C++11. Try making this change in `CMakeLists.txt`:

`if(UNIX OR APPLE)
-  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC -Wall")
+  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC -Wall -std=c++11")
 endif()`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace the newest version of protobuf with protobuf v3.5.1.

```
wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/v3.5.1.zip
```

You need to download to source code, and compile it yourself.